# Access a child method from another child class

Tags: java, inheritance, libgdx, hierarchy

```
public class Game {
   public class Truck {
      private float x,y;
      public Truck() {}
      public float getX() {return this.x;}
      public float getY() {return this.y;}
   }
   public class Fort {
      public Fort() {
        float x = truck.getX();
        float y = truck.getY();
      }
   }

   public Truck truck = new Truck();
   public Fort fort = new Fort();
}
```

Beginner Java programmer trying to make a game.
Getting an error when I try to get truck's x and y values to use in Fort's class method. So is it possible to call a method from another child class?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kroy.game.ETFortress.getTruckDistance(ETFortress.java:178)
    at com.kroy.game.ETFortress.<init>(ETFortress.java:60)
    at com.kroy.game.KroyGame.create(KroyGame.java:45)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:151)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:128)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. [There is no compiler error for this code](https://ideone.com/a1OXki)

Comment: My question is, how can I call the "truck.getX()" method from Fort class? I've edited my question to add the error I'm getting with what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are creating classes within a class.

1. Separate the Game, Truck, and Fort classes into separate classes.
2. In the Fort Class, create an instance of a Truck:
   private Truck truck;
3. In the Fort constructor, pass a Truck as a parameter and set truck's x and y to the parameter's.
4. Now you can access the Truck's getX() and getY() methods from within Fort.
5. Create an instance of the Fort class in Game. Now all of your classes are connected.

If you really are a beginner, learn the basics before trying to tackle a game. You will get there eventually, but figure out how all the pieces of code can work together first. Then you can make anything.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm actually making the game cuz its a uni project and don't have much time to learn all basics of java :S. The code from the question is just a basic idea of my problem. So its a game with many Forts and many Trucks, where player will only drive 1 truck at a time to destroy forts. Isn't there an easier way instead of passing all trucks to all forts in the constructor? Thanks again

Comment: @MarcelMiro. Pass an ArrayList<Truck> instead of an individual. Then you can have as many as you want. You just have to iterate over them each time you want to find get one. It is probably what I would do.